# Getting critical severity when working with Expo 45 and React-Native 0.68.2

Tags: react-native, expo

I have decided to use expo to start a new project and am running into a problem.

Expo 45 does not have React-Native: 0.69.0 yet. But I am noticing I keep getting as the recommended fix for a critical problem

```
shell-quote  <=1.7.2
Severity: critical
Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in a Command in Shell-quote - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-g4rg-993r-mgx7
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-native@0.69.0, which is a breaking change
```

Anyone has found a solution to this vulnerability? Really don't want to continue coding if I am able to resolve this with the current version. Thank you for all the input/help.